# How to execute Azure DevOps .NET Core CLI task with arguments

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, runtime, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

On Azure DevOps, I want to configure the [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) so that it executes `restore` with runtime `win-x86`.

I tried this configuration:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: './src/MySolution.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'
    arguments: '--runtime win-x86'
```

...which I thought would add `--runtime win-x86` to the executed command.  However, the command that gets executed...

```
/usr/bin/dotnet restore /home/vsts/work/1/s/./src/MySolution.sln --configfile /home/vsts/work/1/Nuget/tempNuGet_158.config --verbosity Detailed
```

...is missing the runtime option.

### On Azure DevOps, is is possible to execute the .NET Core CLI task so that it executes `restore` with runtime `win-x86`?

I first tried to determine if there was something wrong with the documentation of the .NET Core CLI task by creating [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4425), but it was closed without any dialog, and I was essentially told to post my question on SO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it look like the version 2 of the task `DotNetCoreCLI` can't take another arguments in the `restore` command.

Switch the version to 1 - `DotNetCoreCLI@1` and it will work:

[image]

Comment: I determined that it the expected behavior for version 2 to ignore the arguments when restoring.  I added more information to the linked GitHub issue.